# Why would an OO language really need a PROTECTED access modifier?

Tags: oop, access-modifiers, protected

I can understand why there is *public* and *private* access modifier, these two are also found in almost any language. I can even understand why there might be a *package* modifier, as you may want to have your classes (those that tightly belong together) interact with each other in a way, that is not suitable for public interaction (e.g. as it depends upon knowledge of class internals, maybe because it would reveal a secret, or maybe because it may change at any time and relying on it will break all existing code, and so on). However, why would I want to have a *protected* identifier? Don't get me wrong, I know what *protected* means, but why would I want subclasses of my classes to access certain instance variables or use certain methods, just because they are subclasses and even if they are part of a different package? What is a real world use case for *protected*?

(And performance as an argument for instance variables does not count, since a JIT compiler can always inline accessor methods, decreasing their call overhead to zero)

Comment: Just skim through a few classes from the Javadoc and you'll see a bunch of "real-world use cases" :)

Comment: I see only cases where a public method would have done no harm to anyone in the world or where a package method would have made more sense than a protected one (since the class has not been designed subclassing outside of the package in the first place).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Public methods are part of the public interface. Private methods are internals. Protected methods are points of extension.

With `protected` you can redefine the functioning of a class by overriding it without making this method part of the public interface.

Another thing - protected methods are common methods that can be reused by subclasses, but again don't need to be part of the public interface.

For example, in the java collection framework, there is the the `AbstractList` class. It has protected `modCount` field and a protected `removeRange` method:

- the `modCount` field is used (incremented) by all subclasses to count the number of modifications. The `Iterator` returned by `AbstractList` makes use of that field
- the `removeRange` method can be reused by subclasses, instead of having them define it again.

[See this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAb7hSCtvGw) related presentation by Josh Bloch on API design.

As noted in the comments, and in the presentation by Bloch - document your class well. And if it is meant for inheritance - make extra effort.

Comment: Why would a non-subclass not be allowed to query the number of modifications? What's so "evil" about this information? And why would the rest of the world not be allowed to do a removeRange call?

Comment: the number of modifications matters only to the Iterator created by Abstract list. The rest of the world should not call removeRange - I don't know. I think I remember Bloch mentioning something about this in a lecture, but can't find it.

Comment: The fact that a piece of information is not interesting to the rest of the world is no argument for not allowing the rest of the world to access it. Actually since it is not interesting, the rest of the world probably will never access it anyway, even if they could. And what stops the rest of the world to just subclass my subclass of AbstractList, only use this sub-subclass and offer this information via a different method?

Comment: @Mecki If there was public access to `modCount`, I could use it to mess up my collection while it's being iterated without it being known to the iterator. This is basic encapsulation.

Comment: So a subclass using this field incorrectly cannot mess up anything? And if I'm allowed to subclass and thus there is documentation how to use this field correctly, to not mess up the collection, I also know how to use/not use this field, if I don't subclass, don't I? Despite the fact, that no ivars should ever be public IMHO, access to ivars should always go over methods that manipulate them.

Comment: @Mecki - if you subclass, you will be able to screw only _your_ collection. But if it was publicly accessible, you will be able to screw every collection.

Comment: If you make `modCount` public, it becomes part of your contract, and people will start relying on it. If you later decided that `modCount` isn't useful any more, because you have a new `ChangeTracker` class, you cannot remove `modCount` without breaking all the code that relies on it.

Comment: @Mecki Maybe you have a component with several configurable features.  In that component's constructor it may call several protected methods: initAccessibilityDisplay(), initLookAndFeel().  Subclasses can provide the desired accessibility and look and feel options by overriding these methods.  You certainly don't want these methods to be public since they should only ever be called once and only ever called by the base class.

Comment: Okay, this sounds like a valid objection. Of course you could argue, that since it is documented how to use it correctly (for the sake of subclassing), its the programmers fault for not using it correctly. On the other hand, by that argumentation, we could abolish all modifiers and just document which ones are private or should only be used by a certain package. You may like to add this comment to your answer -> accepted.

Comment: @Mecki That's what they did with Python. Everything is public.

Answer (score 3):

The most frequent use I see is actually to let a superclass use a subclass's internals. Consider this:

```
class Foo
{
    private int[] array = new int[] { 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    public void processAllElements()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            processElement(array[i]);
    }

    protected abstract void processElement(int i);
}

class Bar
{
    protected void processElement(int element)
    {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

In this case, it's `Foo` that needs to use the protected element of `Bar`, and not the opposite. If you want your superclass to access the logic of a subclass, but don't want it to be publicly exposed, you have no choice but the `protected` modifier. This is called the template method pattern, and it's often used. (Sorry for not providing a real-world example. [Head to Wikipedia if you want some.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern))

Comment: In this example, what would be so bad about making processElement public? Will it break anything? Reveal any secret information? If you allow programmers from the outside world to subclass your class, the information is not secret anyway (since you want people to override it).

Comment: @Mecki This is a trivial example. Nothing bad would happen if it was public. However, this method could deal with internals in a way that you'd prefer it to be non-public. And since it can't be private because the superclass needs it, you're left with `protected` only.

Comment: @Mecki If you understand the necessity of `private` methods, I'm sure you can understand why template methods can't always be `public`. If there was no inheritance involved, such methods would be `private`. But since you need it from the superclass, you need `protected`.

Comment: But if you allow people to subclass your class, the information about this method is by definition public. The person that subclasses your class will usually be the same person that also uses it. How can this person not know those internals if this person needs to know them for subclassing?

Comment: Private methods are part of information hiding in OO languages. Just answer this simple question: Why would I want a subclass to access some piece of information, but the rest of the app not, if the person that writes the subclass can be the same as the person that writes the rest of the app? What makes his own subclass special compared to all the other code he writes? If he knows how to correctly subclass your class, he also knows when/how to call this method from outside and when not to.

Comment: @Mecki Because using a method at an untimely moment can bring your object into an unstable state, and this is a violation of encapsulation. So if you make it public, your interface allows anyone to put your object into an unstable state.

Comment: @Mecki Besides, how can you know for sure all implementors of template methods _will_ be the users of the subclasses?

Answer (score 0):

I see them as a shortcut when you don't fully know the mind of possible extenders. Say your base class has 5 or 6 attributes. You certainly don't want those attributes (or their set methods) public. But you can see that extenders might want to write functions that would change the values of those attributes. So you make them (or better, their sets) protected. There will always be reliance-on-design that might be ok for an extender but isn't ok for just any old consuming code.

That said, I tell my students "protected is a to-do list". Because if you change anything protected, you have to go looking to find who relied on it. So be really sure about something before you expose it to the unknown extenders of the future.

Comment: Why would I allow extenders to do that, but the rest of the world not? What makes extenders, which are part of the rest of the world different from the,...well..., "the rest of the world"?

Comment: You wrote, say, BankAccount. You think that someone might write SavingsAccount or TaxProtectedAccount and that code in those classes might need to change balance or overdraft limit or other attributes from the base class.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that languages exist which do not have a `protected` access modifier, and even languages that do not have access modifiers *at all* where all methods are public, *and* those languages are generally considered to be some of the "most pure" OO languages, shows that you do, in fact, *not* "really need" a `protected` access modifier.

Answer (score 0):

A public member in a public inheritable class constitutes a contract with the entire world which is binding upon all well-behaved subclasses.  A protected member constitutes a contract with any immediate subclasses, which is only binding upon the class which is exposes it.  Subclasses are under no obligation to expose any protected members to their own subclasses (indeed, there should be a convention for denying such exposure, as well as a means of specifying that a particular protected member should by default only be available to immediate subclasses unless those subclasses specify that it should be available to their subclasses as well).

Some people may chafe at the idea of a class not allowing access to protected members exposed by its parent, but such behavior is not in any way a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle.  The LSP states that if code may receive a derived-type object when it expects a base-type object, the derived-type object should be able to do anything the base-type object can.  Thus, if `Moe` publicly supports a feature and a type `Larry`, which derives from `Moe` doesn't, code which accepts a parameter of type `Moe` and tries to use that feature would fail if it was given a `Larry`; such failure would constitute a violation of the LSP.

Suppose, however, that `Moe` includes a `protected` feature which `Larry` does not support.  The only classes that would be allowed to use that feature would be either those that directly derive from `Moe`, or from descendants of `Moe` that support it.  If `Curly` derives from `Moe`, it can use that feature without having to worry about whether all subtypes of `Moe` support it, because `Curly`'s base won't be some arbitrary object that's either an instance of `Moe` or a derivative (and might or might not support the feature)--it will be a `Moe`, period.

It is possible for protected fields to introduce some LSP-related issues if derived types use those fields in a manner which breaks public members of the base which use them.  On the other hand, one needn't use protected variables for that.  If a subtype implements virtual members in a way which differs from the expected behavior of the base type, that may break public members of the base type, even without touching any base-class protected members.

Answer (score 0):

I personally utilize the protected modifier when I want to a) eliminate noise in the public contract yet b) also share functionality with derived classes while in-turn c) writing code that is DRY and it also mindful of the single responsibility principle. Sounds typical I'm sure but let me provide an example.

Here we have a basic query handler interface:

```
public interface IQueryHandler<TCommand, TEntity>
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> Execute(TCommand command);
}
```

This interface is implemented by many different query handlers in the application. Let's say then later that I have a need to cache the query results from many different query handlers. This is really just an implementation detail though. The consumers of any concrete query handler class aren't, generally speaking, concerned about that. My solution then is to create an implementation that takes care of the caching but defers the actual querying responsibility to any derived classes.

```
public abstract class CachedQueryHandler<TCommand, TEntity> 
    : IQueryHandler<TCommand, TEntity>
{
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Execute(TCommand command)
    {
        IEnumerable<TEntity> resultSet = this.CacheManager
            .GetCachedResults<TEntity>(command);

        if (resultSet != null)
            return resultSet;

        resultSet = this.ExecuteCore(command);
        this.CacheManager.SaveResultSet(command, resultSet);

        return resultSet;
    }

    protected abstract IEnumerable<TEntity> ExecuteCore(TCommand command);
}
```

The CachedQueryHandler doesn't intend for anyone else to call the ExecuteCore method directly. It also doesn't care how the querying is implemented though. The protected modifier is perfect for a scenario like this.

Also, I don't want to be repeating that same boiler plate type of code in every query handler particularly because it would be a nightmare to refactor if the cache manger interface changed and a real pain to take out if caching was removed completely at this level.

Here is what a concrete widget query handler would look like:

```
public class DatabaseWidgetQueryHandler : CachedQueryHandler<WidgetCommand, Widget>
{
    protected override IEnumerable<Widget> ExecuteCore(WidgetCommand command)
    {
        return this.GetWidgetsFromDatabase();
    }
}
```

Now, if the consumers of the widget query handler utilize it via the query handler interface, which if I utilize dependency injection I can certainly enforce, they will never use anything specific to caching that is added to the CachedQueryProvider class. I'm then free to add/remove caching as necessary or change the caching implementation entirely even with a minimal amount of effort.

```
IQueryHandler<WidgetCommand, Widget> widgetQueryHandler;
var widgets = widgetQueryHandler.Execute(myWidgetCommand);
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably, there is some information/property which you will share with your children, even if they are married and live in another country. BTW, there are languages which don't have the  `protected` modifier.

Comment: But you have not given a reason why I would not want to share it with the rest of the application? And if I don't want to share it with the rest, why not using "package" for that? (where package can be seen as "family" to follow your sample)

Comment: @Helgi @Mecki the analogy is the following: "package" means living at the same place, "protected" means family. There is something that you would share with your family, but not with your neighbor. And "family" doesn't mean living at the same place (i.e. in the same package). I hope I explained well this time :)